# What version of Ubuntu for a Compaq Armada E500?

Tags: distro-recommendation

The machine runs windows 98SE at the moment. I would like to install ubuntu on this 15 year old laptop and maybe use it as a reddit machine or run some emulators on it (haven't decided yet).

SPECS:

512MB ram (maxed out)

5GB Hard drive

550MHz celeron CPU

800x600 screen resolution

ATI rage pro mobile 8MB video card.

Comment: A server edition might work, though it would be a slow server indeed.

Comment: The other hardware might be workable, but I imagine the 8MB video card will be the biggest restriction. If you can't upgrade that, I'd stick with a text-only distribution/mode to avoid your tiny RAM being taken up in hardware compensation.

Comment: I think I will go with text only. Maybe openbox in case I need a GUI for anything.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I've setup one of those for my mother with LUBUNTU. It has been working for a couple of years with version 10.04 LTS.
I'm actually trying to upgrade it to Lubuntu 14.04, but I'm having some issues with chromium and some library.
It works with Firefox but it's a bit sluggish.

I've tried several distros and Lubuntu has been the best that I find for old machines.

Try the dark theme with Moka icons and it will look beautiful!

Comment: Will do, just got some things on my plate ATM